# Not able to load data in collection view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http

I get data from one URL and i encode my password & did shaa256 and again i pass the password to get data form my url

**URL  :  http://exampleurl/users**

And i can able to print my Json response in my console .its working fine.Now i want to show my data in my collection view ( like grid form).I did all story-board work and i did all delegate method.

My problem:

1. Getting error `'UICollectionView dataSource is not set'`
2. My data are not loading in collection view.

Help me out THANKS IN ADVANCE !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your `refresh Data`

```
for(int i=0;i<[arrayFiles count];i++)
{
    NSString *strCreatedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"created_time"]];
    NSString *strLastModifiedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"last_modified_time"]];
    NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"]];
    NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]];


    [arrayPDFName addObject:strName];
}
```

**After that call this line on reload/refresh/update the data**

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
[self.mycollectionView reloadData];
});
```

for your First Error

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


self.mycollectionView.dataSource = self;
self.mycollectionView.delegate = self;

 [self getdata];

}
```

check in your .h file, make certain to declare that your object conforms to the data source & delegate protocols.  E.G.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
```

Comment: Yes its work for only one section.Having 2 questions:                                      1. i have 3 more section and need to tell collection view they are empty           2. In header in need every section name with their file count (eg: blue(3), white(0) ....like my image showed above

Comment: bro for my above question

Comment: you need to crate the 4 seperate  array and store .   else crate one array and add 4 dictionaries and store the value

Comment: bro see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483940/section-name-number-of-data-present-and-not-able-to-display-all-section-data

Comment: bro please look at this post and needed help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483940/section-name-number-of-data-present-and-not-able-to-display-all-section-data

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `mycollectionView` in `viewDidLoad` is not set. Just connect outlet property to storyboard.